# How can I complete Bwemba's Spirit?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Observe my quest log:

[image: Bwemba's Spirit in my Quest Log]

I have highlighted the quest "Bwemba's Spirit", in which I am tasked with finding "the other Darkspear Emissary". I'm pretty sure this refers to Vol'jin, the red-haired fellow standing immediately to the right of my quest log window. I was under the impression that I'd completed this quest already, but apparently Bwemba isn't ready to acknowledge that we've located Vol'jin.

Is there some other quest I still have yet to do? I spent a good 20 minutes today flying around Stranglethorn Vale to try to find a missing exclamation point, but I couldn't see one. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, it looks like you're mounted (I see the Griffin icon in your auras bar, and you appear to be flying): to trigger the quest completion, you need to be *dismounted*.<sup>1</sup>

If you still haven't completed it, try walking into the Inn<sup>2</sup> or logging out and logging back in.<sup>3</sup>

#### Note

These suggestions come from the comments on Wowhead's [Bwemba's Spirit quest page](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=29100/bwembas-spirit), but Stack Exchange breaks Wowhead-style anchors:

<sup>1</sup> Anchor `#comments:id=1400267` by skeletalroach
<sup>2</sup> Anchor `#comments:id=1403297` by Sledgehammer
<sup>3</sup> Anchor `#comments:id=1405033` by WyvernVJ

Comment: Man, if **that's** all it took to resolve this, I'm going to feel awfully sheepish. Let me try that and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

I found an NPC in the Explorer's League Digsite in Stranglethorn. The NPC's name is Colin Swifthammer. To get the quest Making Contact. This helps finish the quest Bwemba's Spirit.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make sure that the spirit is with you. From what I remember, she runs behind you while you walk/fly around. If she isn't with you, trying logging out and back in again and she should respawn next to you. Next, you need to dismount and wait about a minute or so for the spirit to register that you are standing next to Vol'Jin. When the spirit finally wakes up, an event should trigger.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To complete this quest you need to fly around Stranglethorn. There are a few tasks the spirit will ask you to do on the way to Booty Bay. She also speaks about some of the changes there on the way. Make sure to fly over each town on the way to Booty Bay, afterwards you get to Vol'Jin quest should be completed.